# Srcolling to a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My site has blog posts played out down the page… In the top right, I have navigation, with an option to jump to the last post in September. I know the id of the div that contains this post is `#post2`, so I'm trying to use jQuery to scroll the page to that div, like this:

```
$("html, body").animate(
    { scrollTop: $("#post2").offset().top },
500);
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo) function, by calculating the according coordinates, but if you are using jQuery there are out-of-the-box ready plugins with smooth scrolling support like [jquery.scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Here a Code-Snippet that demonstrates it:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    $.scrollTo('#post2', 800 );
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;  
}

#large {
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#post2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js?1.4.11"></script>

<button id="btn">scroll</button>

<div id="large"></div>
<div id="post2"></div>
```

In your case you need to add `overflow: hidden;` to the `UIPostContainer` class, since you can not scroll to an element without a height. And because you have a ~50px height fixed header that overlays everything you have to account for that as well, e.g. like that: `$.scrollTo("#post2 h4", 800, {offset: {top:-55} });`

Comment: This is doing the same thing! As I comment on another answer, I may have been unclear in my question… If you click on 'September 2014 Posts,' the page should scroll alllll the way down to the very first post. Instead, it only scrolls about 200 or so pixels down.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! This has been such a headache. It's interesting that adding `overflow: hidden;` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is 100% right it has no mistake

and as I saw your site is working too

Comment: Maybe I was unclear in my question… If you click on 'September 2014 Posts,' the page should scroll alllll the way down to the very first post. Instead, it only scrolls about 200 or so pixels down.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but the behavior you want is not there because the height for the divs of postcontainer like $('#post2) is not correct (it is 0px) in terms of styling.